# rails console in production resets entire database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment

I am just testing the production environment in my laptop. I used the command

`RAILS_ENV=production rails console`

It somehow drops all tables and recreates them and that too picks up some old schema and does that. Now because of that the latest app doesnt run. Same with unicorn

`bundle exec unicorn`

Any ideas where is it picking up the schema file from. I have deleted the db/schema files as well. I now only have the migrations.

Comment: The production database is separate from development have you executed ,`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Also `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec unicorn` you must run all production commands with the env passed in

Comment: Why is it running half the migrations. Also I have run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`. After that rails console and unicorn resets the database

Comment: Interesting watch: the schema.rb has some old columns in it. What is it used for anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Not because of anything else but schema.rb file. The preload option in unicorn runs the schema.rb file as well and then we loose the data in the database since in the schema.rb file, it is mentioned  force=true. Deleted the file and everything worked fine.